# How to get the attribute values

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

My HTML line is like this

```
li a name="1:2" in die autem tertia apparuit homo veniens de castris Saul
veste conscissa et pulvere aspersus caput et ut venit ad David
cecidit super faciem suam et adoravit
```

I want the output as

```
1:2 in die autem tertia apparuit homo veniens de castris Saul
veste conscissa et pulvere aspersus caput et ut venit ad David
cecidit super faciem suam et adoravit
```

Now i am getting the output as

```
in die autem tertia apparuit homo veniens de castris Saul
veste conscissa et pulvere aspersus caput et ut venit ad David
cecidit super faciem suam et adoravit
```

number is missing

I am using this condition:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li"))
{
    //coding
}
```

I am storing the HTML contents in SQLite database.

How can I get the values of attributes?

Comment: is your string hardcoded or generic? You can use regular expressions or can use string.split functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetAttributeValue` to get value of *name* attribute:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li")){

    string liName = node.GetAttributeValue("name", ""));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GetAttributeValue to get values.